# On mobile; notifications panel has see-through background, rendering it unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, notifications, mobile-web

As of today the notifications panel on mobile has gone see-through; rendering it effectively unreadable. So far I have seen this on the following:

- Default Android browser (android 4.3)
- Chrome (android 4.3)
- iPhone (reported by Aaron Bertrand)

[image]

Comment: +1 was just about to file the same issue. It seems to have lost its background definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry 'bout that.

Should be fixed on Meta in rev 2014.1.20.1872 and elsewhere in rev 2014.1.20.1316.

Comment: Welcome to the dev team, Anna! :-D